# How can I query the list of FULL table names in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a need to iterate over all of the tables in my database.  I am doing so with thsi query:

```
SELECT so.name, so.*
FROM sysobjects so
WHERE so.xtype = 'U'
```

This works fine for all of the tables in the 'dbo' schema, but it doesn't work for any other schemas.  I want the output to be like this:

Users.Address
Users.TelephoneNumbers
dbo.GlobalSettings
dbo.Configuration

Instead I get this:

Address
TelephoneNumber
GlobalSettings
Configuration

When I try to construct dynamic SQL queries, it fails because it can't find the Address and TelephoneNumber tables because their schema is not the default 'dbo'.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  YOu can use SYSTABLES: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx

Comment: Is this Sql Server 2000 (I believe it is from the SQL you posted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, you should no longer use the deprecated sysobjects and sytables and these views.

Use the "sys" catalog views instead:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

should work on other than the "dbo" schema as well.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
Select Schema_Name + '.' + Table_Name from Information_Schema.Tables
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies - No, information_schema.tables will work on SQL Server. You can refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx

Comment: +1: Sorry about that, I stand corrected & withdraw my earlier statement

Comment: It's important to give Microsoft credit when they adhere to standards :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005/2008:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
```

In SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'
```